# What's the grammatical function of "to luxuriate in their style and emotions" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, infinitives, infinitive-constructions

> These are films to live in, to luxuriate in their style and emotions. (source: [LA Times](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/movies/newsletter/2020-11-25/ma-raineys-black-bottom-happiest-season-superintelligence-indie-focus))

This sentence grates on my ear, and I am not sure it can be parsed as a grammatical sentence. The infinitive "to live in" is an adjectival infinitive modifying "films", much like "things to do". But what about the second infinitive "to luxuriate in their style and emotions"? Is it adjectival as well? Or is it adverbial?

It sounds off to me, because you can't luxuriate something; you luxuriate in something. Is this sentence grammatical? I thought this would work, with the second infinitive also functioning as an adjectival phrase:

> These are films to live in, to luxuriate in their style and emotions *with*.

But this sounds stilted.

Comment: It's the same grammatical function as _to live in_. It's a relative infinitive construction. As for stranded prepositions, you got the first one and the second one is too far from _luxuriate_ to matter. Use it if you wish, but it adds nothing.

Comment: They are infinitival relative clauses. Though they function as modifier of "films", the term 'adjectival' is best avoided since it implies they are adjectives, which they aren't. Note that they have meanings comparable to finite relatives with "can" or "should", as in "These are films that one can/should live in, that one can/should luxuriate in their style and emotions".